# MathJax `\\` newline not rendering. Simply shows the `\\`

Tags: javascript, html, latex, cdn, mathjax

I use the MathJax CDN: `<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`

When I put this into my webpage:

```
Say $P(k, n)$ is the probability of ...\\

By definition, ...
```

all the math renders correctly, but the `\\` shows up as `\\` instead of as a newline, and there is no newline. It just continues on the same line. So it looks like:

```
probability of ... \\ By definition, ...
```

---

I haven't changed anything for a while, and I didn't think this was happening before, so perhaps some update occurred which causes this? But I am not positive it was working before, so it's possible the issue has always been there.

Comment: Is this just about text mode macros? MathJax only handles math mode, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html

Comment: Peter is correct, MathJax does not process `\\` outside of math mode, and never has, so you are misremembering it working in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. While reading the documentation, it does not seem obvious to me how to do line breaks. It mentioned something about expecting that to be handled with HTML, but putting in `<br>` doesn't work because it seems like MathJax escapes it or something (since the actual characters <br> appear, instead of just putting in a newline).

Comment: You need a more complete example.  Outside math mode, use `<br>`.  Inside, use `\\`.  With what you've provided so far, you don't need a line break, you need a displayed equation, which automatically takes care of the line break.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.